# a question about the evaluation of integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\alpha:[0,1] \to R$ be the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1}xd\alpha $$and $$\int_{0}^{1}x^2d\alpha.$$

I know that the Cantor function is continuous and monotone increasing, how can I evaluate the integral above using the properties of $\alpha$? Can someone help me solve this question?

Comment: It might help that the union of all sets on which $\alpha$ is constant has measure 1.

Comment: This is the nondecreasing Cantor function, which is constant on the middle third intervals? If so, then maybe try calculating it as a limit of $\int_0^1 x d \alpha_n$, where $\alpha_n$ are absolutely continuous approximations of $\alpha$. Then for such things you can integrate by parts, etc.

Comment: Then,I tried your way,then I am stuck in integrating $\int\alpha dx$

Comment: These are $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ where $$X=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{U_n}{3^n}$$ and $(U_n)$ is i.i.d. with $P(U_n=0)=P(U_n=2)=\frac12$. For example, the (rather simple) facts that $E(U)=1$ and $E(U^2)=2$ (directly) yield $$E(X)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{3^n}=\frac12,\qquad E(X^2)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac2{9^n}+\sum_{n\ne m}\frac1{3^n3^m}=\frac58.$$

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/57721/442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first integral we have by parts$$\int_{0}^{1}xd\alpha\left(x\right)=\left.x\alpha\left(x\right)\right|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\alpha\left(x\right)dx=1-\int_{0}^{1}\alpha\left(x\right)dx
 $$ and since $\int_{0}^{1}\alpha\left(x\right)dx
 $ is the area of the Cantor function on $\left[0,1\right]
 $ we get $$\int_{0}^{1}xd\alpha\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2}.
 $$ For the second integral see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139217/calculate-integral-with-cantor-measure)